# Why during animation between two 'div' there is an empty space?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Can anyone help me to remove the white space in between them during animation?

do i need to add one more div wrap both div into one?

I have chosen to use position-top to adjust my div animations is that causing the problem and please suggest me a better method to do this animation if any?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #top {
            background: white;
            color: white;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            display: inline-block;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #first {
            background: blue;
            transition: 0.5s;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #second {
            background: green;
            transition: 0.5s;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var up = true;
        var down = false;
        function animations() {
            if (up) {
                document.getElementById('first').style.top = '-300px';
                document.getElementById('second').style.top = '-300px';
                up = false;
                down = true;
            }
            else if (down) {
                document.getElementById('first').style.top = '0px';
                document.getElementById('second').style.top = '300px';
                down = false;
                up = true;
            }
        }

        //timer events
        var startAnimations = setInterval(animations, 1000);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="top">
        <div id="first">first</div>
        <div id="second">second</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While moving down make your second div element top 0px instead of 300px;

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Anytime @MohanRavi

Answer (score 3):

Don't give style top `300px` while second div goes down, just set it `0px` like first div. Both divs are relative and the first one push the second, so it won't be `300px` it will be `300px + first div`.

```
document.getElementById('second').style.top = '0px';
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Thank you for your help! appreciate ya!

Comment: Please mark Ashish's solution as the answer. He answered first. @MohanRavi

Comment: That's so humble of you!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #top {
            background: white;
            color: white;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            display: inline-block;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #first {
            background: blue;
            transition: 0.5s;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #second {
            background: green;
            transition: 0.5s;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var up = true;
        var down = false;
        function animations() {
            if (up) {
                                      
                up = false;
                down = true;
            document.getElementById('first').style.top = '-300px'; 
                document.getElementById('second').style.top = '-300px';

            }
            else if (down) {
                down = false;
                up = true;
                document.getElementById('second').style.top = '0px';
                document.getElementById('first').style.top = '0px';
                
            }
        }

        //timer events
        var startAnimations = setInterval(animations, 1000);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="top">
        <div id="first">first</div>
        <div id="second">second</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Mohan Ravi check it. if any doubt let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Its because of your relative positioning.
Use the given css:

```
#top {
            background: white;
            color: white;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            display: inline-block;
            overflow: hidden;
            position:absolute;
        }

        #first {
            background: blue;
            transition: 0.5s;
            height: 300px;
            width:300px;
            position:absolute;
        }

        #second {
            margin:0px;
            background: green;
            transition: 0.5s;
            height: 300px;
            width:300px;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #top {
            background: white;
            color: white;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            display: inline-block;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #first {
            background: blue;
            transition: 0.5s;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #second {
            background: green;
            transition: 0.5s;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var up = true;
        var down = false;
        function animations() {
            if (up) {
                document.getElementById('first').style.top = '-300px';
                document.getElementById('second').style.top = '-300px';
                up = false;
                down = true;
            }
            else if (down) {
                document.getElementById('first').style.top = '0px';
                document.getElementById('second').style.top = '0';
                down = false;
                up = true;
            }
        }

        //timer events
        var startAnimations = setInterval(animations, 1000);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="top">
        <div id="first">first</div>
        <div id="second">second</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```